# QGIS3 Remote Debug referencing old breakpoints

Tags: qgis-3, pydev

I've had remotedebug and PyDev working well for a while but at some point it will loose track of the break points and reference those from a prior PyDev debug server startup. I can fix this by creating a new project in eclipse (4.11.0) and copying across the python files - but the new project must use a new project name. It will then work for while.

What I've tried that doesn't work: Deleting the eclipse project and starting a new project with the same name, restarting eclipse/remotedebug or the PyDev server.

Anyone know where PyDev keeps the break points (so I can go in a delete them)? I assume it is not in the eclipse project directory. Are breakpoints only supplied over the debug server or is there a shared file between eclipse/PyDev and QGIS3 remotedebug?

Even if I clear all breakpoints in eclipse using the breakpoints window in the debug perspective it will still stop at an old breakpoint. I have to stop the PyDev server for my QGIS3 plugin to continue.

Any ideas?